# How to display kruti dev 10 hindi font in dropdownlist in asp .net?

Tags: asp.net

I have set dropdownlist data source to acceess a file but it display font in english instead of kruti dev 10. I have set font of dropdownlist to kruti dev 10. But still it display font in english. [image]

Comment: Change the page encoding to UTF-8, use Unicode compliant font such as Arial and use google transliterate to type text in Marathi and add text in Marathi instead of using fonts. That way, if you do a view source - you'll see the dropdown items showing in Marathi. Look at google.co.in for example. That page doesn't use any specific fonts to achieve this.

Comment: I have to use kruti dev 10.

Comment: Just FYI - the website wont be searchable if the search is made in Marathi text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manage localization setting on your **.config** file. It would be easy if you put some codes in the question. Anyway, check out this article on CodeProject 
[Multilanguage Dropdownlist Box](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/136272/multi-language-app_resources-dropdownlist-box-engl)

Comment: I need to use Kruti Dev 10 I have aceess db with entries in Kruti Dev 10.

Comment: What sort of data source is the dropdownlist associated with?